# How can I continue time of the timer when I opening / closing the child window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, timer, mobile-application, dispatchertimer

I have a timer. in my form is still possible to open the child window. when I open and close this window, the timer starts again. How can I continue timer operation when I open and clos the child window??? I hope very much for your help!
this is my timer:

```
Private timer As DispatcherTimer
Private CountUp As Integer

Public Sub DispatcherTimerSetup()

    timer = New DispatcherTimer()
    timer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
    timer.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As Object)

    CountUp += 1
    Dim counter As TimeSpan
    counter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CountUp)
    txblCountdown.Text = counter.ToString("mm\:ss")

End Sub
```

child window:

```
    Private Sub btnMapPoint_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    SaveControlValuesInObject()

    Dim intIndex As Integer = CInt(sender.Name.Replace("btnMapPoint_", ""))

    Frame.Navigate(GetType(Location))
    TryCast(Frame.Content, Location).InitForm_Observation(_myEventErist, intIndex, GetType(Event9900000))
    TryCast(Frame.Content, Location).IsChangeMapEnabled = False
    TryCast(Frame.Content, Location).SetSelectedMap(DirectCast(cboMesspunkt.SelectedItem, SMS_KARTE))
End Sub
```

Best regards, Polina

Comment: Could you show the code, which is opening the child window? I assume that child window is re-initialized each time you are opening it.

Comment: Yes, I added the child window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Frame.Navigate(GetType(Location))` will initialize new instance of `Location` page, so `CountUp` value will be lost.

You can make `CountUp` field public and add another field in parent object, for example, `SavedCountUpValue`. Then use `Location.Unloaded` event to save `CountUp` value into `SavedCountUpValue` field.

In parent object, in `Location_Unloaded` handler:

```
SavedCountUpValue = TryCast(Frame.Content, Location).CountUp
```

Then, when initializing new `Location` object, restore `CountUp` value.

In parent object, in `btnMapPoint_Click` handler:

```
Frame.Navigate(GetType(Location))
...
TryCast(Frame.Content, Location).CountUp = SavedCountUpValue
```